# getting error when using with using multiple loggers

Tags: java, log4j

i am using multiple loggers to append into multiple log files.the path of these log files are set dynamically.

i am doing my project in java and using log4j framework.
my project structure.

```
  src 
 log4test
 log4test.java
 log4test2
 log4test2.java
 log4j.properties



 log4test.java:-
 public class Log4Test{


 public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException{
   System.setProperty("logs", "C:\\New folder 3\\logs.log");
   Logger log = Logger.getLogger("file");
   log.info("hello");
  Log4Test2.fefe();
  }

  }
 log4test2.java:-
  public class Log4Test2{
       /* Get actual class name to be printed on */
       public static void fefe()throws IOException,SQLException{
     System.setProperty("logs.file", "C:\\New folder 2\\logs.log");
          Logger log = Logger.getLogger("admin");
          log.info("Debug2");
          log.info("Info2");
       } 
     }
   log4j.properties:-
   log4j.rootLogger=INFO
   log4j.logger.file=INFO, file
   log4j.logger.admin=INFO, admin

   # Define the file appender
   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=$[logs}

   # Define the layout for file appender
   log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.file.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 
   [%p] %m%n

   # Define the file appender
   log4j.appender.admin=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
   log4j.appender.admin.File=${logs.file}

     # Define the layout for file appender
    log4j.appender.admin.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.admin.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} 
    [%p] %m%n
```

i am getting this error:-
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this line

```
 # Define the file appender
   log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
   log4j.appender.file.File=$[logs}  //TODO should be ${logs}
```

If I am not mistaken. Thank you.

The second thought is:

public class Log4Test2{

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("admin");

public void fefe()throws IOException,SQLException{ //try remove static 
    System.setProperty("logs.file", "C:\\New folder 2\\logs.log");
    log.info("Debug2");
    log.info("Info2");
}
```

Comment: but i am getting error for logger admin.and the error is same log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed